# Is there a way to fire jQuery's live() or delegate() without a user event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying use jQuery to poll dynamic DOM nodes, created outside of the jQuery object (with Google Maps API methods). I can do this easily by, for example, binding delegate() to a click event. However, I need to poll the DOM, without any additional user actions (user should not have to click), as part of a function that runs onload. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Edit: I'm using the Maps API to write add a bunch of markers at load. I can do this without any problems, but I need to loop through the HTML the Maps API writes with jQuery and append child nodes. delegate() and live() can this, but the only way I know how to fire delegate() or live() is by binding it to an user event. I'm trying to fire off something like jQuery's delegate with each iteration of my Maps API function, without the user doing anything.

Comment: What do you mean, "poll the DOM"?  Poll it for what?

Comment: Poll it for markers added through Google Map API methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do the call once:

```
setTimeout("doGoogleMapApiCall()", 5000);
```

.. or multiple times:

```
setInterval("doGoogleMapApiCall()", 5000);
```

---

**EDIT:** I think what you are looking for is a custom event? Have a look here: http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/04/custom-events-in-jquery-open-doors-to-complex-behaviors/

Comment: That's kind-of a bad way to do "setTimeout" or "setInterval" - you've already got the function defined, so there's no reason to pass it in as a string. `setTimeout(doGoogleMapApiCall, 5000);` is better.

Comment: I would recommend assigning setInterval's return value to a variable (e.g., myInterval). Then, later in the page if you need to stop polling, you can call clearInterval(myInterval) to stop polling.

Comment: My Map API method already fires at load. My issue is I'm trying to loop through the HTML written by the Map API with jQuery, then append child text nodes.

Comment: Thanks harpax. Writing a custom event looks like the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [LiveQuery plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs). Here is a simple example of its use:

```
$('table tr:even').livequery(function(){
    $(this).removeClass("odd");
    $(this).addClass("even");
});
```

This snippet would automatically apply the "even" class and remove any "odd" class that might be on a table row **dynamically** as new rows are added to the table.